# How to make sqlite3 work in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm trying to start learning ruby on rails and install sqlite3. I actually installed sqlite3 however it doesn't function well like you can see at the bottom.

```
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x64-mingw32]

C:\Users\abc>sqlite3 --v
'sqlite3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\abc>
```

Would you tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Switching to Ubuntu is easier than learning all the hacks required to get Ruby on Rails working on Windows. Once you switch you will never look back, and all the tools you need, like SQLite, will install very easily.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is an embedded SQL database engine. Unlike most other SQL databases, SQLite does not have a separate server process. SQLite reads and writes directly to ordinary disk files. A complete SQL database with multiple tables, indices, triggers, and views, is contained in a single disk file.

Directly downloadable SQLite `.exe` file to maintain `database` [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3170000.zip) then extract to a folder then open SQLite command toll where you can command for database creation, delete, edit or view

[image]

You need marked one `.exe` file, double-click to open then write command which you need.